# How does an iOS device identify itself to server without user log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, authentication, ios5, authorization

I am writing an iOS app with a Rails API backend. The Rails backend will serve JSON data to the app. I have the following requirements.

1. The app will be a free download
2. The app will show data on a map
3. The app will show data in the vicinity of the user
4. Upon loading the app the device should send some unique identifier to the server identifying itself as a device that is running this app.
5. There will be no authentication for the user as it is not required. The data is available to anyone who downloads the app. All the server needs to know is that the client is a device running the app. The server cannot serve data to any other client
6. I would like to run the data using SSL between the device and server
7. The user location will be sent to the server and the server returns the corresponding pieces of data that are in the vicinity of the user
8. The client receives the JSON and caches the data locally.

**Question:** Given these requirements, how to set up steps 4 & 5?

Also: If I want to search more on this topic what keywords should I be googling for?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [OpenUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID) or [SecureUDID](http://www.secureudid.org).

Answer (score 1):

I give you 2 options.

First of all, the easy way. From some time, apple forbids access to the device ID. However, they give you a device token instead.

To get this unique token, the user must register for remote notification.

Upon application launching, call the following function:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Then this callback will be called:

```
 - (void)application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken.
```

Send the token to your server and you're done. Problems with this approach are obvious. Your user will have to register for remote notification.

Another approach is to use the MAC address of the wi-fi board.

To do this:

[IPAddress.h](http://www.chrisandtennille.com/code/IPAddress.h)

[IPAddress.c](http://www.chrisandtennille.com/code/IPAddress.c)

Import this files into your project.
Then use this function:

```
InitAddresses();
GetHWAddresses();

for (int i=0; i<MAXADDRS; ++i)
{
    //There is a way you can obtain more info about the hw_addrs, but in general, it's the first.
    NSLog(@"MAC: %s",  hw_addrs[i]);
}

FreeAddresses();
```

Create a hash using the mac address above and you're done.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I wish you could elobrate on the first part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Upon first launch, the app sends a request to the server saying *Hi, I'm a new client, give me an id!* The server generates a new, random id and sends it back. The app saves the id locally and uses it henceforth to uniquely identify itself.

Comment: Hi Thanks. However, one question. Any client can say they are a "new client" even now iOS devices or iOS devices that are not my clients. How can the server know that the client is an iOS device that is running my app? We dont want any client saying that they are eligible.... Is there a way to get the device id and know from the device id whether its an iOS device running my app?

Comment: To answer this, you can use an identifier as a seed to hash the generated ID. Or you can use the private public key algorithm, providing a signed certificate within your app. It's like using SSL, but you will have control over the application.